# Adding a Supporting File to xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new to xcode, and development in general.  Following a tutorial that tells me to add "file.plist as a supporting file to the project."

Does this just mean add a file to the project?  I placed it into a folder (BT_Config) that has the another .plist file in it already).  Not knowing anything about my project, does that sound right?

I can't find a clear google reference to "xcode supporting files" - so i'm not sure.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

You need to add it to your Xcode project. Xcode will then copy it into the file system folder if needed. Just open your project in Xcode and drag your file into the left sidebar. It doesn't matter where you drop it, but supporting files are usually added to the 'Supporting files' group.

If you want to create a new file, just use the 'File > New > File...' item from the menu bar.